# Set specific DHCP options on a static IP address connection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, dhcp

Our network has some not-commonly used DHCP options on it, including some vendor-specific options (e.g. option `002` for Time Offset set to `0x9AB0`).

I have one particular computer that for whatever reason I want to have a static IP address. (I want to assign additional IP addresses to this network adapter, and you can't have a hybrid static/DHCP connection in Windows. OK so [there's bullshit like this](https://superuser.com/a/472381/3171), but that doesn't fly for me) But when I do this, it loses all these DHCP options and software that relies on them doesn't work.

I'm not too concerned about the vendor-specific options (They are for device auto-provisioning and things like that), but some of the more commonly accepted DHCP options are more important.

Is there any way, in Windows 2008 R2 (or Windows 7) that these DHCP options can be set without actually using DHCP?

Comment: Using reservations is not an option?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - nope; updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, beginning with Windows Vista/2008, Microsoft disabled the ability for a single network interface to use both DHCP and static addresses at the same time. So you're left with workarounds.

One sure-fire way to do this is to put a second NIC in the server. Configure one NIC with DHCP (to pick up a [DHCP reservation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779507%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and all of your DHCP options) and configure the second NIC with your other static IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Huh, just throwing something out, but what about a logon script (group policy?) ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935(v=WS.10).aspx )  bit ghetto but I don't know enough about your setup to know if it would work or not

Comment: Apparently the `netsh` method of doing a hybrid dhcp/static is depreciated in 2008 R2 and Windows 7

Comment: @MarkHenderson It's not just deprecated, it's _gone_.